# Why don't my error templates correctly wrap my validated wpf controls

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, layout

I have a curious problem with rendering validation templates. As I resize my main windows the error templates are not stabilizing on the controls they wrap. This happens for text boxes and comboboxes.

Bad rendering

[image]

Good rendering

[image]

The Error template

```
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="16" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,0" Opacity="0.5">
            <Ellipse Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Red"/>
            <Ellipse Width="3" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 2 0 0" Fill="White"/>
            <Ellipse Width="2" Height="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 0 2" Fill="White"/>
        </Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The style applied to a combo box.

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">

    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}"/>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>


    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Is there an obvious error with the way I'm applying the validation templates?

Comment: I suggest you download Snoop, run the program, then inspect the elements in Snoop.  The other thing is I don't like to set the size of the `Grid` in my XAML; I prefer to let everything size to the available space.  If I do have to set a size in the `Grid`, I usually set the width of columns.

Comment: The sizing of the grid is just to make an exclamation mark icon. I've tried snoop but it doesn't show the validation box at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, my controls have `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` and when the view has loaded the controls resized correctly, but the error template remained unchanged. It happened with the default WPF error template, too. I was playing with Adorners for a while but never find any solution. Finally I did this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyErrorTemplate">
  <Grid>
     <Border
         Width="{Binding ElementName=adornedElementPlaceholder, Path=AdornedElement.ActualWidth}"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         BorderBrush="Red"
         BorderThickness="1"
         CornerRadius="0"
         RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
         SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
         <Border
             BorderBrush="Transparent"
             BorderThickness="5"
             ToolTip="{Binding Path=[0].ErrorContent}" />
         </Border>
         <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adornedElementPlaceholder" Focusable="False" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The key was binding the width of the border to the adornered element. I have horizontal alignement set to left, when I set it to (original) Strech it did not align the border correctly.